# Error when requesting geometry in get_acs(), tidycensus

Tags: r, r-sf, tidycensus

get_acs() suddenly giving an error when requesting with geometry = TRUE. See error message below.
First time getting this error, even though this code has run with no issues before. Any thoughts? Thanks

```
my_vars <- c(
   total_pop = "B01003_001",
   pop_poverty = "B17001_001"
)

tracts_acs <- get_acs(
      geography = "tract",
      state = "CA",
      variables = my_vars,
      geometry = T) %>% 
   select(GEOID, variable, estimate) %>%
   st_transform(6440)
```

Getting data from the 2017-2021 5-year ACS
Downloading feature geometry from the Census website.  To cache shapefiles for use in future sessions, set `options(tigris_use_cache = TRUE)`.
Using FIPS code '06' for state 'CA'
Error : Cannot open "/private/var/folders/zx/5k5b4tzx3gxfj_187kpqzq6w0000gn/T/Rtmpq3ED0D"; The source could be corrupt or not supported. See `st_drivers()` for a list of supported formats.
In addition: Warning message:
In unzip(file_loc, exdir = tmp) : error 1 in extracting from zip file
Error: Your geometry data download failed. Please try again later or check the status of the Census Bureau website at https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/

Comment: Usually this means your computer is having trouble connecting to the TIGER/Line shapefile FTP site.  Can you try again today?  If it still doesn't work, can you make sure tidycensus and tigris are up-to-date and then file an issue on GitHub with your full `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: Yeah, something was corrupt between Tigris and Tidycensus. Seems to be working now after reinstalling. Thanks.